# Exportar excel enviado una variable desde vista AJAX - LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, ajax, excel

Soy nuevo usando la libreria **Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel** y ahora estoy en un gran problema, estoy enviando una variable desde la vista con **AJAX** pero no se como ingresarlo dentro del export para que pueda añadirlo como un filtro al reporte y ademas de eso nose como hacer para que descargue el excel con AJAX, esto es mi avance:

VISTA:

```
<p>Exportar solicitudes por Oficinas</p>
<select class="form-control" name="IdOficina" id="IdOficina" required>
<option value="0">SELECCIONAR</option>
@foreach($oficinas as $o)
<option value="{{$o->IdOficina}}">{{$o->Descripcion}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
<a href="javascript:;" title="Reporte de mis Solicitudes" class="btn btn-success mt-2" id="OficinasExcel">Exportar todas las Solicitudes enviadas</a>

$(document).on('click', '#OficinasExcel', function(){
  var idoficina = $('#IdOficina').val();
  $.ajax({
        url: "{{route('Reportes')}}",
        type: "get",
        data: {_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}", idoficina: idoficina},
        success: function (response) { 

        },
        error: function(response){
          swal("Error!", "Ocurrió un error", "warning");
        }
      });
});
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function SolicitudesXoficinasExcel(Request $request)
{   
    $idoficina = $request->idoficina; //VARIABLE QUE QUIERO INGRESAR AL EXPORT
    $excel = Excel::download(new SolicitudesXoficinaExport, 'SolicitudesXOficinas.xls');

    return $excel;
}
```

EXPORT SolicitudesXoficinaExport:

```
class SolicitudesXoficinaExport implements FromView, WithTitle
{   
use Exportable;
private $idoficina; // declaras la propiedad

public function __construct(int $idoficina) 
{
    $this->idoficina = $idoficina; // asignas el valor inyectado a la propiedad
}

public function view(): View
{    
    $id = $idoficina;
    return view('SolicitudesxOficinasExcel', [
        'tickets' => Ticket::ReporteMisTicketsEnviado($id)
    ]);
}

public function title(): string
{
    return 'SolicitudesxOficinas';
}
}
```

Entonces...como ingresar la variable al export y como hacer que descargue el excel por ajax? Ayuda por favor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para pasarle datos a la clase export, tienes más de una opción. Te muestro una con el link a la documentación.

[Antiguo Objeto PHP plano](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/architecture/objects.html#plain-old-php-object)

Además de ser un DTO, los objetos de importación/exportación también son simples Objetos PHP antiguos (POPO). Esto significa que puedes hacer cualquier cosa con ellos que puedes hacer con objetos PHP normales.

Por ejemplo, simplemente puedes inyectar datos a través del [Constructor](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/architecture/objects.html#constructor) del objeto de exportación.

```
class SolicitudesXoficinaExport implements FromView 
{
    private $id; // declaras la propiedad

    public function __construct(int $id) 
    {
        $this->id = $id; // asignas el valor inyectado a la propiedad
    }

    public function view(): View
    {   
        // puedes acceder a la propiedad aquí con $this->id
        return view('SolicitudesxOficinasExcel', [
            'tickets' => Reporte::ReporteXoficina()
        ]);
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function SolicitudesXoficinasExcel(Request $request)
{   
    $idoficina = $request->idoficina;
    $excel = Excel::download(
        new SolicitudesXoficinaExport($idoficina), // aquí inyectas el valor
        'SolicitudesXOficinas.xls'
    );

    return $excel;
}
```

---

Para lo de descargar un archivo con ajax, hay muchísima información, pero si es una petición GET, te recomiendo que no uses ajax para descargar un archivo.

En vez de hacer una llamada ajax, puedes usar [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/location), asignádole tu ruta con el parámetro (si tu ruta no espera parámetros, cualquier argumento que le pases se agregará como una cadena de queries a la url).

```
$(document).on('click', '#OficinasExcel', function(){ 
    window.location="{{ route('Reportes') }}"+ '?idoficina='+$('#IdOficina').val();
}
```

Comment: Hola que tal me sale este error al momento de poner ese codigo que has puesto en mi vista syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' (View: , pienso que es por el '$' que ingresaste o no se :s

Comment: Tienes razón, mezclé el php con js. Actualicé la respuesta

Comment: buenas ahora en la parte del Export el id que pusiste en el constructor lo cambie por 'idoficina' y me sale el error de 'Undefined variable: idoficina' :s

Comment: He actualizado la parte de EXPORT SolicitudesXoficinaExport: ahi eso agregue nuevo y pues salio 'Undefined variable: idoficina'

Comment: Quita `$id = $idoficina;` de la función view. Tienes que usar la propiedad `$this->idoficina` no puedes usar directamente `$idoficina`. También en `ReporteMisTicketsEnviado($this->idoficina)`

Comment: Ya salio! Eso era lo que no sabia sobre el $this->idoficina, gracias por apoyarme