# Importar datos desde un excel especificando el cliente al cual se le va a cargar?

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy importando un excel a mi sistema y se carga correctamente, pero ahora debo especificar a que cliente de mi lista de clientes voy a cargar esos datos.

Estoy capturando el ID del cliente al cual le quiero cargar los datos a través de un formulario, pero no se los puedo pasar al controlador del import ya que no me lo permite.

La funtion model no me permite pasarle el Request de mi formulario. De que otra manera podría hacerlo?

Este es mi controlador para importar.

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    $usuario = User::select('name')->get()->first();
    $date_comp          = null;
    $date_reten         = null;
    $monto_fact         = $row[7];
    $itebis_fact        = $row[8];
    $itebis_retenido    = $row[9];
    $itbis_perci        = $row[10];
    $reten_renta        = $row[11];
    $isr                = $row[12];
    $impuesto_consumo   = $row[13];
    $otros_impuestos    = $row[14];
    $propina            = $row[15];
    $efectivo           = $row[16];
    $ctd                = $row[17];
    $tarjeta            = $row[18];
    $venta_credito      = $row[19];
    $bonos              = $row[20];
    $permuta            = $row[21];
    $ofv                = $row[22];
     

    // Comprueba si la fecha no es correcta o viene en blanco
    if (($timestamp = strtotime($row[5])) === false) {
        
    } else {
        $date_comp = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $timestamp);
    }

    // Comprueba si la fecha no es correcta o viene en blanco
    if (($timestamp2 = strtotime($row[6])) === false) {
        
    } else {
        $date_reten = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $timestamp2);
    }
    
    
    return new Factura([
        'cliente_id'        => 1,
        'tipo_factura'      => '607',
        'documento'         => $row[0],
        'tipo_documento'    => $row[1],
        'ncf'               => $row[2],
        'ncf_modificado'    => $row[3],
        'tipo_ingreso'      => $row[4],
        'date_comp'         => $date_comp,
        'date_reten'        => $date_reten,
        'monto_fact'        => (float) ($monto_fact),
        'itebis_fact'       => (float) ($itebis_fact),
        'itebis_retenido'   => (float) ($itebis_retenido),
        'itbis_perci'       => (float) ($itbis_perci),
        'reten_renta'       => (float) ($reten_renta),
        'isr'               => (float) ($isr),
        'impuesto_consumo'  => (float) ($impuesto_consumo),
        'otros_impuestos'   => (float) ($otros_impuestos),
        'propina'           => (float) ($propina),
        'efectivo'          => (float) ($efectivo),
        'ctd'               => (float) ($ctd),
        'tarjeta'           => (float) ($tarjeta),
        'venta_credito'     => (float) ($venta_credito),
        'bonos'             => (float) ($bonos),
        'permuta'           => (float) ($permuta),
        'ofv'               => (float) ($ofv),
        'operador'          => $usuario->name,

    ]);
    
}
```

Comment: Puedes inyectar datos a través del constructor. Dale una mirada a esta [pregunta/respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/338604/92278), o directamente a la documentación del paquete https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/architecture/objects.html#plain-old-php-object .

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me sirvió de mucho.